# SSL/HTTPS proxy for apache virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, nginx, https, ruby-on-rails

I currently have an application running on Apache. It uses subdomains to distringuish between user-accounts.

I'd like to add SSL support (wildcard). A solution which is quite common seems to be the following (just use two virtual hosts).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # sauron.com
  # some other app
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # *.frodo.com
  Include app.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  Include a file

  SSLEngine On
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However I'd rather like to have an SSL Proxy in front of the *:80 virtual host. I ran accross mod_proxy but the samples I found do not handle subdomains (or only with manual configuration of each subdomain).

```
 user1.frodo.com:433 -> user1.frodo.com:80
 userX.frodo.com:433 -> user1.frodo.com:80
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this with Apache proxy? Or should I use an additional proxy server (nginx?) for that? Are there any sample configs then (couldn't find any for this subdomain case for nginx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/).  It can do what you're asking for, and a lot more.

Comment: Very nice software, didn't know it. +1